# Store Symmetric-key on a remote server in android

Tags: android, security, https

My app needs a Symmetric encryption key to store game data so the user or anyone else cant modify that. From my research I found that there is no where to save this key safely on device other than hosting my own https server. I want to avoid hosting a costly https server just for this purpose. My question, is there a service/server to store my key that can only be accessed/read by my app.  What I mean by service is third party (e.g google) service provider which enable this process.

Comment: You can try security by obscurity. If the key is derived from password inside the code, taking into account the Android app code is being obfuscated this will relatively difficult to crack. This doesn't provide perfect level of security, but for relatively middle security sensitive data it could be enough.

Comment: Thanks. yes, but I can afford to use only  progaurd which does not do any string obfuscation. I was wandering if I can get the key prom a third party https server.

Comment: Obfuscate string yourself: for example, XOR it with something and save it as byte array.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to go for the difficult and likely overcomplicated route, you could try using [Diffie-Hellman](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/security/crypto/CryptoSpec.html#DH2Ex) to establish a shared secret key between each client and the server.

Comment: TLS already does that and TLS is already implemented in Java.